# Get the currently executing method

Tags: php, oop

I'm fairly new to OOP and I'm trying to get the name of the currently executing class and method. For example:

```
<?php

class ParentExample
{
    function __construct()
    {
        echo get_class($this) . '<br />';
        echo __METHOD__;
        exit;
    }
}

class ChildExample extends ParentExample
{
    public static function test()
    {
        echo 'hello';
    }
}

call_user_func_array([new ChildExample, test]);
```

This is the result I want:

```
ChildExample
ChildExample::test
```

This is the result I get:

```
ChildExample
ParentExample::__construct
```

I've looked at [debug_backtrace()](http://php.net/debug_backtrace) but I don't understand how to decipher the results or if that's even what I need. Is there an easier way to achieve what I'm after?

**EDIT:** Based on the answers I think my question isn't clear. I want the ParentExample constructor to tell me the name of the called method. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want the ParentExample constructor to tell me the name of the called method. Is this possible?

***No***, that is not possible. The constructor is executed when *constructing* the object and only then, this means it's executed *before* you can place any method calls on the object.

---

`echo __METHOD__;` is within the `__construct` method. Since `__METHOD__` always has the value of the method it's in, it can't print `

`__construct` is called when you *create* the object. You create an object by using the `new` operator. This is *not* connected to the static `test` method.

You would have to put `echo __METHOD__` into the `test` method for that to happen ;)

You should use a string to specify the name of the method:

```
call_user_func_array([new ChildExample, "test"]);
// Since you're not passing any arguments, this will do:
call_user_func_array([new ChildExample, "test"]);
```

Comment: I've updated my question. Is it possible to get the called method from within the Parent constructor?

Comment: @mistermartin I have updated the answer. No, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
class ParentExample
{
    function __construct()
    {
        echo get_class($this) . '<br />';
    }
}

class ChildExample extends ParentExample
{
    public static function test()
    {
        echo __METHOD__;
    }
}

call_user_func([new ChildExample, 'test']);
```

Note that I have removed the `exit` call in the parent constructor, and echoed `__METHOD__` from the child class. If you don't the script will end right after `ParentExample` is instantiated.

Also, if you are not using parameters to call the method, you should be using `call_user_func()` instead of `call_user_func_array()`.

Comment: I've updated my question. Is it possible to get the called method from within the Parent constructor?